# Algorithm for computing discrete logarithm in group of order $2^n$

Tags: discrete-logarithm

In my cryptography course our teacher said that solving the discrete logarithm problem in a group of order $2^e$ is easy, and he gave us the following algorithm:

Let $G$ be a cyclic group with $|G|=2^e$ and $g\in G$ a generator. The following algorithm computes $x$ such that $h=g^x$:

- Precomputation: $g^{-1}=g^{n-1}$.
- Inicialization: $x_0=0$, $b_0=h$, $m_0=\log_2(ord(h))$.
- Iterations:
  while $m_i> 0$:
  $x_{i+1}=x_i+2^{e-m_i}$
  $b_{i+1}=b_i(g^{-1})^{2^{e-m_i}}$
  $m_{i+1}=\log_2(\text{ord}(b_{i+1}))$
- Output: $x=x_i$

What I want to do is to prove that the algorithm stops, that $x$ is indeed the discrete logarithm and that it works in polynomial time. In order for the algoritm to stops we only have to check that $m_{i+1}<m_i~\forall~i$, which is equivalent to show that $\text{ord}(b_{i+1})<\text{ord}(b_i)$. If $\text{ord}(b_i)=2^l$ then:
$$b_{i+1}^{2^l}=(b_i(g^{-1})^{2^{e-m_i}})^{2^l}=b_i^{2^l}(g^{-1})^{2^{e-l}2^l}=1$$
which proves that $\text{ord}(b_{i+1})\leq\text{ord}(b_i)$, but I am not able to get the strict inequality. For the other two parts I don't have any good idea on how to solve it...

I am a matematician who is a beginer in cryptography, so I don't mind if you assume math knowledge, which is what I am used to. Thanks for your help.

Comment: 1) I think you need to also assume $G$ is cyclic (for the discrete log to be well-defined, $h$ must be in the cyclic subgroup generated by $g$, so this is no real restriction). Then try to show some properties of elements with order 2. (2) Try expressing $b_i$ in terms of $h$, $g$, and $x_i$.

Comment: @SamJaques you're right, i forgot to say that $G$ is cyclic, thanks

Comment: @SamJaques By induction I was able to prove that $b_n=h(g^{-1})^{x_n}$, which of course implies that if $m_n=0$ we have $b_n=1$ and so $g^{x_n}=h$. This proves that indeed when the algorithm finish we get the discrete logarithm. Thanks :), can you help me  to prove that the algorithm runs in polynomial time?

Comment: Determine the input size; which is common in the number of bits. Then determine the number of operations. Are you sure the $\log_2$ is not floored?

Comment: @kelalaka Yes, it is not floored since we are in a group of order $2^e$, so Lagrange's theorem tells us that the order of every element is a divisor of $2^e$ and so $\log_2(\text{ord}(\cdot))$ will always be an integer.